# libcurl fails with error code 56 (ssl_read) and error code 58 when server reboots and doesn't recover post reboot

Tags: openssl, libcurl

Communication from client to server using libcurl handle (easy interface) is failing if the server is rebooted.

The program (code pasted below) creates a curl handle, initializes options like url, certificates, timeouts, request, etc. Then after in an infinite loop for every 2 seconds sends request to server using curl handle.

Observations are as below:

1. After the program has started, client to server communication is established properly and messages are exchanged without any error.
2. Later I powered of the server machine. When server is powered off, curl_easy_perform failed with error code=28, "Timeout was reached (connect() timed out!)".
3. Then I powered on the machine, while the machine is booting, observed curl_easy_perform failure with error code=7, "Couldn't connect to server(couldn't connect to host)".
4. Once curl handle was able to connect to server port, observed ssl_read error, curl error code=56, "Failure when receiving data from the peer (SSL read: error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate, errno 0)"
5. Further onwards curl_easy_perform fails with error code=58, "Problem with the local SSL certificate (unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?))" and never recovers after that.
6. If I stop the program and restart, the connection is established successfully. There is no change in certificates.

I am not able to find why `curl_easy_perform` fails with ssl_read error and why further onwards says error code =58 (unable to use client certificate).

Since communication works with same certificates initially and also after restarting the process, I think there is no issue with certificates.

I tried openssl commands to verify certificates are correct.

```
Linux# openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in /opt/certstore/VcCombined.pem | openssl md5
fe18e9f364d18eba9f39690563aca836

Linux# openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in /opt/certstore/default.key | openssl md5
fe18e9f364d18eba9f39690563aca836

Linux# openssl verify -CAfile /opt/certstore/sslca/CACertificate.pem /opt/certstore/VcCombined.pem
/opt/certstore/VcCombined.pem: OK
```

I am not sure how to debug this issue further. If its an issue with openssl or curl or my program.

Client side:

```
curl --version

curl 7.25.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.25.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8f zlib/1.2.1.2 libidn/0.5.6
Protocols: dict file gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

Server side:

```
curl --version

curl 7.25.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.25.0 OpenSSL/1.0.0e zlib/1.2.1.2 libidn/0.5.6
Protocols: dict file gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

Program:

```
using namespace std;

static std::string buffer;

static int writer(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string *buffer)
{
    int result = 0;

    if (buffer != NULL)
    {
        buffer->append(data, size * nmemb);
        result = size * nmemb;
    }

    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    char request[4096];
    char curl_errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
    int bytes_read = 0;

    FILE *lFile = fopen("/tmp/getguid.xml", "r");
    if (lFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("fopen Error: %s\n", strerror(res));
        return 1;
    }

    memset(request, 0, 4096);
    bytes_read = fread(request, sizeof(request), 1, lFile);
    fclose(lFile);

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    struct curl_slist* lcurlHeaders = NULL;
    lcurlHeaders = curl_slist_append(lcurlHeaders, "Content-Type: text/xml");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, lcurlHeaders);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://10.65.124.221:443/xmlInternal/service-reg/forward");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    char *lUCSInterfaceName = "eth0";
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, lUCSInterfaceName);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "/opt/certstore/VcCombined.pem");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, "/opt/certstore/default.key");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/opt/certstore/sslca/CACertificate.pem");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, (char*)request);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(request));
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, curl_errbuf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);

    while(1)
    {
        memset(curl_errbuf, 0, CURL_ERROR_SIZE);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(CURLE_OK != res)
            printf("curl_easy_perform Error: %s (%s)\n", curl_easy_strerror(res), curl_errbuf);
        else
            printf("curl_easy_perform succes\n");

        sleep(2);
    }

    curl_slist_free_all(lCurlHeaders);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to monitor what happens on the system level ? Is the old SSL connection dropped ? Maybe try to sniff the successful handshake with wireshark and try to sniff the incorrect handshake too to see the difference.